# Why are Amazon reviews under the wrong product?

Tags: amazon

When you go to [Premium-PC-Steckernetzteil](http://www.amazon.de/Premium-PC-Steckernetzteil-Ladeger%C3%A4t-Raspberry/dp/B00V0UU392/) ("Rydges® High-Quality PC Netzteil - by OTB 2A - / 2000 mAh Ladegerät 5V 2000 mAh für Raspberry Pi Modell A und B & Banana Pi - Pi Model B+ (B Plus)" - I'm sorry, it's the German amazon website) you can see from the title it is about a power supply unit for raspberry pi. However, when you scroll down to the ratings / reviews it is clear that they are about cases for raspberry pi.

See the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELKs7.jpg) for an image of the page. It is quite large, so I don't want to include it here directly.

Why did Amazon mess that up? Is it a bug?

Comment: I'm seeing a different version of this problem nowadays: [swapped product listings](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121183/swapped-product-listings-on-amazon/121186).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An amazon user just send me the answer. Amazon seems to relate reviews to the "page", not the product. This makes perfect sense for T-Shirts which come in different sizes. Sadly, in this case the seller put different products on the same page (see image below). This means the reviews of all those different products get mixed.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why Amazon allows sellers to modify the product a page is for. They are bastardizing their review system and Q&A system and therefore violating their customers' trust and harming their quality of service.

Comment: I agree. This is a market opportunity to clean up on Amazon.